# Django CMS - navigation order

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I want to integrate an app to Django CMS. Therefor I followed the [documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/app_integration.html#app-integration) of Django CMS.

For example: I use the following code (from doc) in menu.py of my app.

```
from menus.base import Menu, NavigationNode
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class TestMenu(Menu):

    def get_nodes(self, request):
        nodes = []
        n = NavigationNode(_('sample root page'), "/", 1)
        n2 = NavigationNode(_('sample settings page'), "/bye/", 2)
        n3 = NavigationNode(_('sample account page'), "/hello/", 3)
        n4 = NavigationNode(_('sample my profile page'), "/hello/world/", 4, 3)
        nodes.append(n)
        nodes.append(n2)
        nodes.append(n3)
        nodes.append(n4)
        return nodes

menu_pool.register_menu(TestMenu)
```

My problem is the order of the nodes. With this code my menu will be appended on the menu of my cms pages, but I need a different order.

Is there some way to define on which position my app menu appears?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my workaround, so far. (I still would prefer a more clean way.)

I added a CMS page named `--appname--` and this is my `menu.py`:

```
from menus.base import Menu, NavigationNode
from menus.base import Modifier
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool

my_items = ["a", "b", "c"]

class ImmoMenu(Menu):

    def get_nodes(self, request):
        nodes = []

        i = 0

        for name in my_items:
            i += 1
            n = NavigationNode(name, "/", i, attr={'appname': True})
            nodes.append(n)

        return nodes

menu_pool.register_menu(ImmoMenu)


class ImmoModifier(Modifier):

    def modify(self, request, nodes, namespace, root_id, post_cut, breadcrumb):
        if post_cut is not True:
            return nodes

        split_passed = False

        nodes_before = []
        nodes_after = []
        nodes_immo = []

        for node in nodes:
            if node.title == "--appname--":
                split_passed = True
                continue

            if 'appname' in node.attr:
                nodes_immo.append(node)

            elif split_passed:
                nodes_after.append(node)

            else:
                nodes_before.append(node)

        return nodes_before + nodes_immo + nodes_after

menu_pool.register_modifier(ImmoModifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me out, Sven!!
I wasn't aware of the existence of modifiers...

Below is a refinement of your code.
It will insert app nodes at arbitrary locations.
Each app node has a targetIndex attribute, giving it's zero-based place number on the menu.
Sorry for  the camel-case, but I use a mix of programming languages and one style to fit them all.
In the example, app nodes are inserted at even place numbers, 'follow' is the name of my app.

```
    from menus.base import Menu, NavigationNode, Modifier
    from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool

    class FollowMenu (Menu):
        def get_nodes (self, request):
            nodes = []
            for i in range (5):
                nodes.append (NavigationNode (('Test' + str (i)), '/', i,  attr={'targetIndex': 2 * i}))
            return nodes

    menu_pool.register_menu (FollowMenu)

    class FollowModifier (Modifier):
        def modify (self, request, nodes, namespace, root_id, post_cut, breadcrumb):
            if not post_cut:
                return nodes

            appNodes = [node for node in nodes if 'targetIndex' in node.attr]
            cmsNodes = [node for node in nodes if not 'targetIndex' in node.attr]

            resultNodes = []

            appNodeIndex = 0
            cmsNodeIndex = 0
            for resultNodeIndex in range (len (nodes)):
                if appNodeIndex < len (appNodes) and appNodes [appNodeIndex] .attr ['targetIndex'] == resultNodeIndex:
                    resultNodes.append (appNodes [appNodeIndex])
                    appNodeIndex += 1
                elif cmsNodeIndex < len (cmsNodes):
                    resultNodes.append (cmsNodes [cmsNodeIndex])
                    cmsNodeIndex += 1
                else:
                    raise Exception ('Error merging app menu and cms menu items')

            return resultNodes

    menu_pool.register_modifier (FollowModifier)
```

Comment: How does this differ from Sven's answer (how have you improved it?)